# Run a executable JAR file from the command line with Classpath

Tags: java

I have a Spring boot jar which I can run using the below command.

> java -jar sample.jar
>   --spring.config.additional-location=application.properties

But, When I run the same jar with -cp, getting unable to find Main class error.

> java -cp /usr/test/libs/* com.test.Sample
>   --spring.config.additional-location=application.properties

Not sure why it is not able to load the main class with this way?

Comment: Open the jar file (it's a zip file), look at its structure, and look what the main class in the manifest is, and you'll understand.

Comment: Is your sample.jar inside /usr/test/libs?

Comment: Yes. thats an executable jar.

Comment: Can you try `java -cp /usr/test/libs/*:/usr/test/libs/sample.jar ...`